# kubernetes persistent volume overrides the previous volume

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes

We are trying to run blockchain node with AWS EKS.
We need to maintain the previous blockchain snapshot while updating node version.
So we used the kubernetes persistent volume, but the previous volume is just overwritten whenever we kill the previous pod, and restart the new one.

We set up the arguments of docker image to store the data at "/data/headless"
like this

```
--store-path=/data/headless
```

also, we set the volumeMounts to "/disk"

```
volumeMounts:
- name: block-data
  mountPath: /disk
```

and the result shows
[image]

We think this volume path seems a temporary volume, and we are wondering about how to maintain these volumes even if we update the pods.
[We have seen millions of documents of AWS, but still doesn't know where to get started:( ]

How can I update the previous volume and connect it to new pod without losing any data in the previous one?

Here's our source code.

#### Volume Claim Yaml File

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nine-claim-3
spec:
  storageClassName: gp2
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

#### StatefulSet & Service Yaml File

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: nine-cluster
  namespace: test-nine-3
  labels:
    app: nine
spec:
  serviceName: nine-cluster
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nine
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nine
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nine-container
        image: planetariumhq/ninechronicles-headless:v100260
        ports:
        - name: rpc
          containerPort: 31238
        - name: iceserver
          containerPort: 3478
        - name: peer
          containerPort: 31234
        - name: graphql
          containerPort: 80
        args: [
        "--port=31234",
        "--no-miner",
        "--store-type=rocksdb",
        "--store-path=/data/headless",
        "--graphql-server",
        "--graphql-host=0.0.0.0",
        "--graphql-port=80",
        "--rpc-server",
        "--rpc-remote-server",
        "--rpc-listen-host=0.0.0.0",
        "--rpc-listen-port=31238",
        "--no-cors",
        "--chain-tip-stale-behavior-type=reboot"
        ]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: block-data
          mountPath: /data/headless          
      volumes:
      - name: block-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nine-claim-3
                  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nine-nlb-services
  namespace: test-nine-3
  annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: instance
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
spec:
  ports:
    - name: graphql
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31003
      protocol: TCP
    - name: rpc
      port: 31238
      targetPort: 31238
      nodePort: 31004
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nine
```

Comment: whats the `RECLAIMPOLICY` policy for the claim?

Comment: We didn't set RECLAIMPOLICY at all. Is that associated with our problem?